# How to add value from Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, addition

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Money");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            int total=0;
            for (ParseObject p : objects) {
                total += p.getInt("kwota");
            }
            saldo.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        } else {
            saldo.setText("brak");
        }
    }
});
```

I'm working on an application for Android, it's kind of calculator. I add data to parse how much money I earn and how much money I spend, so every row have value (how much money) and describtion. Now i need to add up all values from the column "value" and show it in another Activity. How can I do that? I have this code, and it doesn't work. How to do correct for loop?

Comment: What do you get when you run this code what show on the textView

Comment: It shows "0". When I change int total=2 textView show "2".

Answer (score 0):

First get the old value

```
int oldValue = parseObject.getInt("key");
```

Second add the amount to the oldValue

```
parseObject.put("key",oldValue+amount) ;
```

Don't forget to save

```
parseObject.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.